# My script can't execute alter database command SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a database then I create a procedure. When I want to `alter` this database, I got an error while altering this database says:

```
create/alter must be the first statement in a query batch
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one statement to run use 'GO' command:

```
alter database xyz ...
GO

INSERT INTO myTable() ...
GO
```

etc